# Getting error The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation, kernel-panic

I have one VM on VMware Workstation. All of sudden VM stop responding with a message "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine" on workstation dashboard.

Base machine where vmware is installed is having i5-4570 CPU "Core(s) per socket: 4 and Thread(s) per core: 1". I have assigned cpu to VM as "Core(s) per socket: 1, Socket(s): 4 and Thread(s) per core: 1)".

Can someone check whether I assign cpu core properly. Is there any logic/formula to assign cpu to VM? Here I assign all the core to vm. Is this creating this issue?.